# Angular material date range smDateTimeRangePicker

Tags: angularjs, daterangepicker

I am planning to use the angular materials date range picker from smDateTimeRangePicker. From the demo I can add the picker as an directive element and it creates an input element which when clicked opens the picker. I would like to add the picker to a button click. Could anyone of you tell me how to add the picker to a button click?

https://github.com/mominsamir/smDateTimeRangePicker